# Polymer2.0 - Looking for json format icon - { } using paper icon

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-2.0

I was looking for json format icon from the polymer iron icons list which is not available

something similar to http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icons-alphanumeric/072287-high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icon-alphanumeric-bracket-curley.png

I am tried below workaround but it didnt work either

```
<paper-icon-button id="json">{}</paper-icon-button>
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rwqYYZ

```
<head>
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<div class="toolbar">
</head>

<body>
      <paper-icon-button id="json">{}</paper-icon-button>
      <paper-icon-button id="save" icon="icons:save"></paper-icon-button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<paper-icon-button>` has a [`src` property](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/elements/paper-icon-button#property-src) to specify the URL of the desired image. You could even specify the `.png` URL you indicated in the question, like this:

```
<paper-icon-button src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icons-alphanumeric/072287-high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icon-alphanumeric-bracket-curley.png"></paper-icon-button>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/owapzL?editors=1010)